# Arrays of interface instances in SystemVerilog with parametrized number of elements

Tags: arrays, interface, verilog, system-verilog

I'm using SystemVerilog for synthesis. I fought with the fact that arrays of interfaces are not really arrays in SystemVerilog and the index has to be a constant value, but got over it using at lot of boilerplate `generate for` and `assign` statements to overcome what is really a language limitation (if I can emulate the effect using more code, the language could just do The Right Thing(tm) itself).

For the following pseudo-code, I leave out much of what's there in the real code (modports, tasks, etc) for clarity.
I have an interface:

```
interface i_triplex();
logic a;              // input wire
logic b;              // output wire
logic [127:0] data;   // output wires
endinterface
```

And I am passing an array of these interfaces to a module which looks like

```
module roundrobin_triplex#(
    parameter int NUNITS = 8
)
(
    input wire clk,
    input wire rst,
    i_triplex t[NUNITS]
);
always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
    if (rst) begin
      // insert code to initialize the "data" member
      // in all interface instances in the array.
    end
    else begin
      // ...
    end
end
endmodule
```

What would your preferred way to use all interface instance in the array uniformly -- regardless of the value of `NUNITS`? I have some suggestions, but I am eager to learn what other engineers can come up with.

**Suggestion 1:**
Use VHDL.

**Suggestion 2:**
Scrap the interface and do it oldschool Verilog-style, as in

```
module roundrobin_triplex#(
    parameter int NUNITS = 8
)
(
    input wire clk,
    input wire rst,
    // This was once a proud i_triplex array
    input wire i_triplex_a[NUNITS],
    input wire i_triplex_b[NUNITS],
    input wire [127:0] i_triplex_data[NUNITS],
);
always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
    if (rst) begin
        for (int i = 0; i < NUNITS; i++)
            i_triplex_data[i] <= '1;
    end
    else begin
        // ...
    end
end
endmodule
```

**Suggestion 3:**
Use a `struct` for input wires and a `struct` for output wires instead of the interface.

**Suggestion 4:**
Use a preprocessor-like system that unrolls `generate for` loops inside processes (what the language should do anyway!), so the resulting code looks like (preprocessed with NUNITS=4):

```
module roundrobin_triplex#(
    parameter int NUNITS = 8
)
(
    input wire clk,
    input wire rst,
    i_triplex t[NUNITS]
);
always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
    if (rst) begin
        i_triplex.data[0] <= '1;
        i_triplex.data[1] <= '1;
        i_triplex.data[2] <= '1;
        i_triplex.data[3] <= '1;
    end
    else begin
        // ...
    end
end
endmodule
```

**Suggestion 5:**
Use the `generate for` / `assign` solution:

```
module roundrobin_triplex#(
    parameter int NUNITS = 8
)
(
    input wire clk,
    input wire rst,
    i_triplex t[NUNITS]
);

wire i_triplex_a[NUNITS];
wire i_triplex_b[NUNITS];
wire [127:0] i_triplex_data[NUNITS];

generate
genvar i;
// The wires of the interface which are to be driven
// from this module are assigned here.
for (i = 0; i < NUNITS; i++) begin
    assign t[i].b = i_triplex_b[i];
    assign t[i].data = i_triplex_data[i];
end
endgenerate

always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
    if (rst) begin
        for (int i = 0; i < NUNITS; i++)
            i_triplex_data[i] <= '1;
    end
    else begin
        // ...
    end
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays of module or interface instances cannot be treated as regular arrays because parameterization, generate blocks, and defparam statements can make elements of the array instance non-unique. That cannot happen with arrays of variables/wires.

My suggestion would be a modification of your suggestion 2; put arrays of variables/wires inside a single interface instance.

Comment: Maybe the language should be extended to check whether all interface instances in an array are "similar enough" (or let the user use a keyword to indicate that) and allow such interface instance arrays to be used like regular arrays. That  would solve *a lot* of problems when using interfaces for synthesis.

Comment: I have literally hundreds of modules using that interface, most of which use it as a normal interface port, but many use things like `i_triplex t[NUNITS+2]` for mux'ing with other interface instances. I hope to get by without rewriting too much code so I will check if a combination of your modification of suggestion 2 and some `generate for`-`assign` glue code will work so I can leave most of the other modules as they are and use something like an `i_triplex_array` interface for occurrences where it is beneficial.

Comment: Yes, I agree we would need some new syntax. Trying to come up with rules based on usage make an already too complicated language even more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

how about suggestion #6, use parameterized interface:

```
interface I #(NPORTS = 8);
   logic clk;

   logic a[NPORTS];
   logic b[NPORTS];
   logic [127:0] data [NPORTS];

endinterface // 

module roundrobin#(NUMPORTS = 8) (I t);
   logic [127:0] data[NUMPORTS];

   always_ff @(posedge t.clk) begin
      data <= t.data;
   end

endmodule // roundrobin
```

Note, that you do not need the loop in system verilog. you can use array assignments:

```
data <= t.data;
```

and for the sake of convenience you can add functions or statements to the interface itself, i.e.

```
interface I #(NPORTS = 8);
   logic clk;

   logic a[NPORTS];
   logic b[NPORTS];
   logic [127:0] data [NPORTS];

   function logic [127:0] getData(int n);
      return data[n];
   endfunction // getData

endinterface // I
```

and use

```
 data[i] <= t.getData(i);
```

Sorry, the above example is probably not very useful, but it might give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion 1**: VHDL may be a practical. However, it seems to become marginal in industry.

**Suggestion 2**: In my opinion, Interfaces are relevant if you intent to reuse it widely and implement verification/protocols into it. If you can unpack your interface like this, while keeping your sanity, then I do not see a justification for an interface in the first place.

**Suggestion 3**: I never tried to synthesise `struct`, it may be a good idea.

**Suggestion 4**: Simple solution,although quite verbose .

**Suggestion 5**: I used something similar for one of my project. However, I wrote a sort of adapter module to hide the assigns.
Actually, when I need something like that, I try to write an atomic module which operates on a fixed number of interfaces. Then, I use `for generate` structures to generalize it on an interface array.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something by why not putting all yours code from roundrobin_triplex into generate (you do not need extra assigns)

```
interface i_triplex();
    logic a;              // input wire
    logic b;              // output wire
    logic [127:0] data;   // output wires
    initial $fmonitor(1,data);
endinterface

module roundrobin_triplex#(parameter int NUNITS = 8)
(
    input wire clk,
    input wire rst,
    i_triplex t[NUNITS]
);
    genvar i;
    for( i=0; i<NUNITS; i++)begin
        always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
            if (rst) begin
                t[i].data <=0;
            end
            else begin
              t[i].data <=t[i].data+1;
            end
        end
    end
endmodule

module top;
    parameter P=4;
    bit clk,rst;
    i_triplex ii[P]();
    roundrobin_triplex #(P)uut(clk,rst,ii);
    initial begin
        rst=1;
        repeat(2) @(posedge clk);
        rst=0;
        repeat(10) @(posedge clk);
        $finish;
    end
    always #5 clk =~clk;
endmodule
```